# Jenkins Pipeline: Advice for restarting and continuing jobs that may reboot the slave machine?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Consider the unfortunate scenario of a driver test suite which runs 1000 tests, but it's possible for these tests to panic the slave machine every so often, due to driver bugs. When a panic happens, testing should reconnect after the slave reboots, and continue running the test suite from where it left off.

AFAICT, the "checkpoint" command for Jenkins Enterprise's Pipeline plug-in may be relevant here, as it should cause the same job to be restarted. Notes [here](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/chapter-workflow.html#chapter-workflow_workflow-sect-checkpoint) also suggest that if the checkpoint is inside a node block, it might achieve the desirable effect (in this case) of causing the job to be restarted on the same machine and node as before (though this pattern is warned against). If the job could be restarted in the same workspace, I'd be able to use previous output files to restart the suite appropriately at the right point.

Having said all this, using Jenkins Enterprise is currently a non-starter for me, so I'm keen to learn if similar functionality can be achieved with the free version. I've read that the free version's Pipeline plug-in does handle "reconnection" to slaves, but can anyone confirm what that means? (I presume this just applies to temporary network outages, where the slave keeps running.) But if a slave was rebooted in mid-job, as above, would the whole pipeline get dropped, or would the server continue with the next stage, or what?

Another whole approach would be to just use Jenkins for job scheduling to "controller" nodes on the Master, with each node talking to the actual test machines over some different protocol. However, it would be nice to keep the whole setup within Jenkins, if possible.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the ideal answer, but it has worked for us for several years on Windows slaves.  Basically, have a bunch of steps that do the work and generate the artifacts that you need. Then, add a step with the following commands:

```
shutdown /r /t 30
exit 0
```

As long as the post-build steps such as archiving artifacts run within 30 seconds, the job will finish successfully and move on and the node will reboot.  Additional jobs in the pipeline will wait until the Jenkins slave is back online before starting.  So, as long as another job doesn't start before the reboot, all is well.