# Jenkins Pipeline restarts after node failure but then stays idle at "Ready to run"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pretty simple Jenkinsfile for my declarative pipeline. I simply call a powershell core script. That then calls python for a long running program.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                withCredentials(...) {
                    pwsh script: './myscript.ps1', encoding: 'UTF-8'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using

- Jenkins 2.375.1
- Built-In Node on Windows Server 2019
- https://plugins.jenkins.io/powershell/ (Version 1.8)

Jenkins tries to restart the pipeline after the node restarts because of either

- a crash (ex: loss of power),
- upgrading Jenkins,
- upgrading/installing plugins,
- manual restart ([www.myjenkinsurl.com/restart](http://www.myjenkinsurl.com/restart))

In the console output I see this:

```
2023-02-17 21:23:06.096 INFO     some log message
2023-02-17 21:23:06.216 INFO     another log message
Pausing (Preparing for shutdown)       (this line printed for upgrade or manual restart, but not for crash)
Resuming build at Fri Feb 17 21:34:52 EST 2023 after Jenkins restart
Ready to run at Fri Feb 17 21:34:53 EST 2023
```

The job stays idle indefinitely. It does not rerun the pwsh script. I have to manually abort the build and start another one.

How can I have Jenkins correctly restart automatically this step after the node is restarted?

NOTE: A very similar issue was apparently fixed in 2020-05-11 on Jenkins 2.46.1 for "Pipeline fails to resume after master restart/plugin upgrade"(https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-43587)

Comment: Would a [clean reboot help](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/16231)? (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348722)) (after [putting the node offline first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51862423))

Comment: Clean reboot didn't help.

Comment: Try checking the node connectivity, Jenkins logs, pipeline script. If still no luck, try running the pipeline on a different node, and make sure you update Jenkins and plugins